# Special charcters in Android using PhoneGap

Tags: android, internationalization, cordova

Im using PhoneGap to develop an android application. 
The problem is characters like ã â á ç are shown like ? (question mark)
Has someone an idea to solve the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the UTF-8 character set on your page. You can tell the browser to do so by adding this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

... to the `<head>` section of your page.

Comment: You're right; my apologies. If I add the same `<meta>` tag above but specify utf-8 as the charset, it works for me. I will amend my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

In my Phonegap & jQueryMobile app, deployed on Android 4.0.3 device, I got a nastly little bit of this stuff showing up in my checkboxes:

```
â€,
```

That was the little critter in my case. I did not get any success with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, charset=utf-8">
```

But what did work was setting the charset as a direct attribute of the meta tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

So it's worth your while experimenting exactly how to specify the charset.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, however even after following above answers, I am getting that little ? mark symbol.

Comment: THAt DID THE TRICK!

Answer (score 1):

Do you use Eclipse? If so, I believe here is what you are looking for:

[UTF-8 unreadable in phonegap android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419507/utf-8-unreadable-in-phonegap-android)

(Project - Properties - Resource: Text File Encoding - Other [UTF-8]).