# UTF-8 unreadable in phonegap android

Tags: html, encoding, cordova

I'm working on my first phonegap application, an android based simple form app.

My problem is that all my non-latin characters appear unreadable.
I added the content meta tag with utf-8, made sure I saved the file as utf-8, made sure to use font with the needed letters and also added xml:lang to the  decleration.

Couldn't find any other idea, because i'm a web dev and this usually solves these issues...

Maybe someone has any idea?
feels like my questions back when I just started web development :)
Thanks!

Comment: Just came to my mind - maybe the emulator itself supports only english?

Comment: ok checked - still the same on an external phone

Comment: I tried running the index.html file in a browser, there all chars appear correctly...

Comment: What platform are you running on? Do you have some sample .html?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just add meta:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Eclipse, which is default for the PhoneGap Android, make sure you applied the utf-8 text file encoding. (Project - Properties - Resource: Text File Encoding - Other [UTF-8]).

The meta tag should also be in your index.html

```
<head>
   <meta charset=utf-8>
   ...
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks man! you saved my day by pointing me in the right direction with that Eclipse shit.

Answer (score 2):

sometime it happens from visual studio page Unicode setting: for this go to file > advance save options > select Unicode utf 8 with signature and then click ok.