# Utf-8 in PhoneGap Build

Tags: android, html, encoding, cordova

My app (android) does not display special characters (ä, ü, ö, €,...), 
The index.html is utf-8 and I use the meta tag for this as:"meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /"
what wrong with me?

Comment: how you get those special characters? are they sent throu ajax? or are they hard coded? need more info about code

Comment: There is similar question to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798472/special-charcters-in-android-using-phonegap. You may look at the answers there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing something similar that is described in this question [Swedish characters and UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365526/swedish-characters-and-utf-8)